# Spacing Content in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been using Bootstrap for the past couple of weeks, and I love the grid system and the interesting usage of HTML5 Data Attributes, but one thing I can't seem to get my head around is spacing.

I can create `row` one after another, or even just containers, and as much as their are evident gutters between each column (`col-md-*`), there is nothing vertically to space your content.

In my most recent project, I created some divider classes just to add some vertical margins in between some of my containers -- but this feels redundant.

How are you supposed to go about properly spacing your content?

Comment: Hard css is the only way... I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, there are no special classes in Bootstrap for that. But I think, it's for good.

Bootstrap cannot always "know", how many space you will need. You must create it yourself. That's why you are a developer :)

Look at these solutions: [Add vertical blank space using twitter bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273588/add-vertical-blank-space-using-twitter-bootstrap):

1) use bootstrap build-in class `form-group`

```
<div class="form-group">
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

2) or add additional block after every row you need:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" style="height:50px;"></div>
```

3) or create a new class and add additional block after every `row`  you need:

CSS:

```
.spacer { margin:0; padding:0; height:50px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

4) Or, if you really need space after **every** row element, add additional style for `row` class:

```
.row { padding-bottom: 50px }
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/3a36p06h/