# Bootstrap - align button to the bottom of card

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I was peeking at one of the Bootstrap examples that use the `card-deck` and `card` classes ([Pricing example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/pricing/)). I wondered how one can fix the button alignment if one of the lists has fewer items than the others.

[image: Alignment issue]

I would like all buttons to be vertically aligned (at the bottom of each card) but I couldn't figure out a way of doing this. I tried setting the [`.align-bottom`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/vertical-align/) class as well as wrapping the button in `<div class="align-text-bottom">`. I also tried several suggestions from [this question about adding space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12273588/3767239) however still no success (also the spacing should be variable such that it fills up the remaining space from the list).

Wrapping in [`<div class="card-footer bg-white">`](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#card-groups) didn't yield the desired result either as it doesn't align the button at the bottom of the card and it creates some kind of border around it.

Does anyone have an idea?

**Edit:** Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpb6d8j9/) that resembles the problem.

Comment: You can always position it as `absolute, bottom:0, margin:0 auto`, with their parent set as `position: relative`

Comment: @Paulie_D I tried setting `style="margin-top: auto;"` however that doesn't change the situation. The button sits exactly where it was before. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpb6d8j9/).

Answer (score 278, accepted):

You can use the following Bootstrap 4 modifier classes:

1. Add `d-flex` to `.card-body`
2. Add `flex-column` to `.card-body`
3. Add `mt-auto` to `.btn` nested in `.card-body`

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vopxn9h9/)

Refer to [this page](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/) for a full list of flexbox modifying classes for Bootstrap 4.

Comment: I did have to set "h-100" for 100% height also on .card-body to work, but maybe my fault? Thanks for nice answer!

Comment: This works for Bootstrap 5 too. Also, I'm using `.h-100` class along with `.card` for the parent `div` element.

Answer (score 31):

A similar question has been [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45058004/aligning-items-within-a-bootstrap-4-card-using-flexbox).

Just add the `align-self-end` class to item to align at the bottom.

https://www.codeply.com/go/Fiorqv1Iz6

```
     <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$15 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
              <li>20 users included</li>
              <li>10 GB of storage</li>
            </ul>
            <button type="button" class="align-self-end btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary" style="margin-top: auto;">Get started</button>
     </div>
```

By default, the `card` is display:flex, but the `card-body` is not. Because of this you need to add `d-flex flex-column` to the `card-body`. This will make the flexbox alignment classes work.

Another option is to use `mt-auto` (auto top margin) on the button which will push it to the bottom of the Card.

Comment: it seems in 4.4.1 the card is not flex, I needed to add .d-flex to the .card to make it work

Answer (score 13):

## Add a Footer to the Card

You can set a footer for every card, like this:

```
<div class="card-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" onclick="location.href = '';">BUY NOW </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Set the `.card-body` div to `display:flex` and `flex-direction:column`.

Then give the button `margin-top:auto`.

I imagine there are Bootstrap help classes for this.

```css
.card-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

button.btn {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Free</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$0 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
          <li>10 users included</li>
          <li>2 GB of storage</li>
          <li>Email support</li>
          <li>Help center access</li>
          <li>10 users included</li>
          <li>2 GB of storage</li>
          <li>Email support</li>
          <li>Help center access</li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Enterprise</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$29 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
          <li>30 users included</li>
          <li>15 GB of storage</li>
          <li>Phone and email support</li>
          <li>Help center access</li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Contact us</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the footer, it already has everything setup for you.

```
<div class="card-deck">
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Title goes here</h4>
      <p class="card-text">Ut leo enim, fermentum fermentum tempor sit amet, vehicula in felis. Pellentesque a arcu augue. Nam eu malesuada lorem. Curabitur et molestie lacus.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="card-footer text-muted mx-auto">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Click me!</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then you can optionally style the card-footer element.

```
.card-footer {
  background: transparent;
  border-top: 0px;
}
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rustynox/203zwyq6/

Answer (score 5):

surround the button in the card with a div tag containing the class with **mt-auto**

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center mt-auto">
<a href="#" target="_blank" target="_blank" type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-3">GitHub</a>     
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the button to occupy the maximum length of the card and be at the very bottom as in the example, just put it in a **div** with **class : class="d-grid gap-2 mt-auto"** and in the center image description file add **display: flex** and **flex-direction: column;** in class **.card-body**.

HTML:

```
      <div class="d-grid gap-2 mt-auto">
      <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-lg btn-outline-dark">Sign up for free</a>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
.card-body {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;}
```

Here you can find my code and screenshot with example:

https://www.codeply.com/go/Fiorqv1Iz6 - code

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqtpI.png - screenshot

Answer (score 1):

## Flex is your friend

Something like this will work the magic:

```css
.flex-wrap {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: inherit;
  -ms-flex-align: inherit;
  align-items: inherit;
}

.flex-container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}


.flex-item {
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}


.fill{
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

.btn{
  background:#069;
  padding:10px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrap">

  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">FREE</div>
    <div class="flex-item fill">
      <h2>$0</h2>
      <p>Some text ... ashd iaush diuhasd uhasd aiusdh iaush d haisduhaiusdh iaush d haisduh aisuhd ias u</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <a href="#" class="btn">SIGN UP</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">PRO</div>
    <div class="flex-item fill">
      <h2>$10</h2>
      <p>Some text ... ashd iaush uhasd aiusdh iaush d haisduhdiuhasd aiusdh iuhasd aiusdh iaush d haisduhaush d haisduh aisuhd ias u</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <a href="#" class="btn">GET STARTED</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">ENTERPRISE</div>
    <div class="flex-item fill">
      <h2>$20</h2>
      <p>Some text ... ashd iaush diuhasd aiusdh iaush d haisduh aisuhd ias u</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <a href="#" class="btn">CONTACT</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

sample is ( d-flex flex-column )

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xl-4" style="float:right">

            <div class="bg-white d-flex flex-column" style="width:100%;height:530px;border:1px solid #808080;border-radius:10px;padding:15px;float:right;margin:10px;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title" style="padding:0px 0px 20px 0px;text-align:center;border-bottom:1px dashed #000000">@item.SiteName</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin:10px;width:94%">آدرس سایت : @item.SiteUrl</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" style="margin:10px;width:94%">رتبه الکسا : @item.SiteAlexa</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin:10px;width:94%">اتوریتی : @item.MozAutoraty</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin:10px;width:94%">لینک : @item.LinkToYou</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin:10px;width:94%">اسپم اسکور : @item.SpamScore</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="margin:10px;width:94%">قیمت : @item.Price</button>
                </div>
                <a href="/Home/About/@item.SiteId" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">توضیحات رسانه</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: class="bg-white d-flex flex-column"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add buttons to the bottom of all cards in Bootstrap, you can use the **card-footer** class. The card-footer class is used to create a footer section for the card, and it is designed to be positioned at the bottom of the card.

Example:

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    Card Header
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    Card Body
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

`enter code here`

Answer (score -2):

This issue is mainly caused when the text of the card is uneven, so the best answer I have found after searching for two hours is to just add this line in the card which has less text than the others:

```
<p class="invisible" > invisible</p>
```

I know it is not a good way to tackle a problem but it is the simplest one I have found.