# Bootstrap 4 button in row alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have two buttons in a bootstrap 4 flex row that refuse to align vertically. I want to align bottom with the inputs on the same row.

[image]

The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bigalnz/xcbj6mpf/).

The code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="card-header">SEIZED BY</div>
<div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="control-label control-label-left" for="OC">O/C</label>
            <input id="OC" type="text" class="form-control textbox" data-role="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label class="control-label control-label-left" for="SeizedByName">Name</label>
            <input id="SeizedByName" type="text" class="form-control textbox" data-role="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <label class="control-label control-label-left">Station</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" name="query" id="query" placeholder="Type Station" data-provide="typeahead" autcomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="mt-auto btn btn-primary align-item-centre" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signature">
                Signature
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="control-label control-label-left" for="OC">Witness</label>
            <input id="Witness" type="text" class="form-control textbox" data-role="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label class="control-label control-label-left" for="SeizedByName">Name</label>
            <input id="WitnessName" type="text" class="form-control textbox" data-role="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <label class="control-label control-label-left">Station</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" name="query" id="query1" placeholder="Type Station" data-provide="typeahead" autcomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signature">
                Witness Signature
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried adding `mt-auto` to the `<button>` element as per this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48406628/bootstrap-align-button-to-the-bottom-of-card) but it ad no apparent effect.

`d-flex` and `flex-column` are already added to card-body.

I would like the solution to use bootstrap helper utilities. The buttons also touch the inputs on small screens.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use this code `align-items-end` in each group of `form-group`:

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div class="container">
<div class="card-header">SEIZED BY</div>
<div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="row form-group  align-items-end">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="control-label control-label-left" for="OC">O/C</label>
            <input id="OC" type="text" class="form-control textbox" data-role="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label class="control-label control-label-left" for="SeizedByName">Name</label>
            <input id="SeizedByName" type="text" class="form-control textbox" data-role="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <label class="control-label control-label-left">Station</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" name="query" id="query" placeholder="Type Station" data-provide="typeahead" autcomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 ">
            <button type="button" class="mt-auto btn btn-primary align-item-centre" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signature">
                Signature
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row form-group align-items-end">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="control-label control-label-left" for="OCQID">Witness</label>
            <input id="Witness" type="text" class="form-control textbox" data-role="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label class="control-label control-label-left" for="SeizedByName">Name</label>
            <input id="WitnessName" type="text" class="form-control textbox" data-role="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <label class="control-label control-label-left">Station</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" name="query" id="query1" placeholder="Type Station" data-provide="typeahead" autcomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signature">
                Witness Signature
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: That worked. Any tips for the margin/padding on top of button on sm screen sizes?

Comment: you can add the class " mt-4  "  in each div of each button

Comment: I have found that it works on lg and xs - but on sm and md the buttons extend beyond the card right hand edge.

Comment: try to use this "pl-md-0 pl-lg-3"  next to " mt-4 "

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.align-items-baseline` after using  `.flex row.`