# Place a button in the bottom of a column in Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to place a button to the bottom of the column with no success.

I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48406628/bootstrap-align-button-to-the-bottom-of-card) so I added the `d-flex`, `flex-column`, `mt-auto` CSS classes but they aren't have any effect.
What am I missing?

```css
.my-200 {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row justify-content-around">
  <div class="col-2 my-200">
  </div>
  <div class="col-10 flex-column">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-12">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input name="comment" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row mt-3">
      <div class="form-group col-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">button 1</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row mt-auto">
      <div class="form-group col-4">
        <button class="btn btn-dark">place bottom</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a `row` ***BS class selector*** class in the `flex-column` element effectively making it a flex container, then place an `align-self-start` ***BS class selector*** on the last `form-row` element that contains the button making `align-self` set to `start`.

```css
.my-200 {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row justify-content-around">
  <div class="col-2 my-200">
  </div>
  <div class="row col-10 flex-column">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-12">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input name="comment" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row mt-3">
      <div class="form-group col-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">button 1</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row mt-auto align-self-start">
      <div class="form-group col-4">
        <button class="btn btn-dark">place bottom</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div
```